# Access files on Dropbox with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, request, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox API with Node JS. I was able to upload files to my Dropbox using HTTP requests, but I am not able to download them with it. My intent is to use HTTP request to view content of the file in the dropbox.

This is the code for uploading files:

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')

var token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
var filename = "path/to/file/file.txt"

var content = fs.readFileSync(filename)

options = {
            method: "POST",
            url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
              "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\": \"/files/"+filename+"\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
            },
            body:content
};

request(options,function(err, res,body){
     console.log("Err : " + err);
     console.log("res : " + res);
     console.log("body : " + body);    
 })
```

Now what should the request function be for downloading this file? I was attempting something like this:

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')

var token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
var filename = "path/to/file/file.txt"

var content = fs.readFileSync(filename)

options = {
            method: "GET",
            url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
              "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\": \"/files/"+filename+"\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
            },

};

request(options,function(err, res){
     console.log("Err : " + err);
     console.log("res : " + res);

 })
```

But the res just gives `object Object`

How do I download the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed to download the file because the URL used(`https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload`) is incorrect. According to **Dropbox** [API document](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download), the correct URL endpoint is:

```
https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download
```

However, it is better to use npm module such as [dropbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropbox) to implement the requirement, as it has already wrapped the logic. The code would look like:

```
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE', fetch: fetch });
dbx.filesDownload({path: '...'})
.then(function(data) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying ```Error: Cannot find module 'isomorphic-fetch'``` even though I did ```npm install``` for it after getting the error the first time

Comment: @RishiC Have you brought your own ES6 Promise compatible polyfill? Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

Comment: Or, you can use another fetch library, `isomorphic-fetch` is just one choice recommended by `dropbox` module, please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: I am not getting how to do that es6-promise part. I downloaded the GitHub repository given, and also did `npm install` on it. But I am still getting the same error

Comment: @RishiC Well, you can try `node-fetch` instead. I think it is easier.

Comment: Now I am getting this error:
`(node:5042) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): #<Object>
(node:5042) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: In my example code, there is no `catch` for promise. So if the promise is rejected, it is not handled. You need to catch the promise yourself and observe which error caused the problem.

Comment: The error is `{ error: 'Error in call to API function "files/download": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": path: \'"/files/file/file.txt"\' did not match pattern \'(/(.|[\\r\\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)\''`

What is the correct way to write the file path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194895/discussion-between-shaochuancs-and-rishic).